# Spring boot failed to load keystore type JKS on tomcat 7 due to "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect"

Tags: tomcat, ssl, spring-boot

I follow [this post](http://nemerosa.ghost.io/2015/07/25/enabling-ssl-with-spring-boot-going-real/) to setup SSL in spring boot. However, it failed to start and threw below exception.

```
ERROR JSSESocketFactory - Failed to load keystore type JKS with path C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\tomcat.5953177593073698207.443\file:/D:/workspace-spring/project/keystore.jks due to C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\tomcat.5953177593073698207.443\file:\D:\workspace-spring\project\keystore.jks (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\tomcat.5953177593073698207.443\file:\D:\workspace-spring\project\keystore.jks (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_45]
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120) ~[na:1.6.0_45]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getStore(JSSESocketFactory.java:413) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.59.jar:7.0.59]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getKeystore(JSSESocketFactory.java:319) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.59.jar:7.0.59]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getKeyManagers(JSSESocketFactory.java:577) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.59.jar:7.0.59]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getKeyManagers(JSSESocketFactory.java:517) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.59.jar:7.0.59]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:493) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.59.jar:7.0.59]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:653) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.59.jar:7.0.59]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:449) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.59.jar:7.0.59]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1007) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.59.jar:7.0.59]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.59.jar:7.0.59]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:241) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.59.jar:7.0.59]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:194) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:151) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:290) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:141) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:540) [spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:347) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:295) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1112) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1101) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at biz.tfsystem.questionnaire.manager.Application.main(Application.java:32) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) ~[na:1.6.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) ~[na:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) ~[na:1.6.0_45]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
```

The project is developed in Java 6, thus tomcat server is restricted to version 7.0.59. I am pretty sure that the keystore location is correct because it can run in Java 8 with tomcat 8. Any clue to fix it?

application.properties

```
server.port=443
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.key-alias=<alias>
server.ssl.key-store=keystore.jks
server.ssl.key-store-password=<password>
```

Project structure

```
project
+-src
+-target
+-keystore.jks
+-pom.xml
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.programmingfree</groupId>
    <artifactId>pf-securing-web</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>javax.transaction-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.6</java.version>
        <tomcat.version>7.0.59</tomcat.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

**UPDATE**

I use below code from Spring Boot [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-enable-multiple-connectors-in-tomcat) to enable HTTPS in Java 6 project.

```
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainer() {
    TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
    tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(createSslConnector());
    return tomcat;
}

private Connector createSslConnector() {
    Connector connector = new Connector("org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol");
    Http11NioProtocol protocol = (Http11NioProtocol) connector.getProtocolHandler();
    try {
        File keystore = new ClassPathResource("keystore.jks").getFile();
        File truststore = new ClassPathResource("keystore.jks").getFile();
        connector.setScheme("https");
        connector.setSecure(true);
        connector.setPort(8443);
        protocol.setSSLEnabled(true);
        protocol.setKeystoreFile(keystore.getAbsolutePath());
        protocol.setKeystorePass("<password>");
        protocol.setTruststoreFile(truststore.getAbsolutePath());
        protocol.setTruststorePass("<password>");
        protocol.setKeyAlias("<alias>");
        return connector;
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("can't access keystore: [" + "keystore"
                + "] or truststore: [" + "keystore" + "]", ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a more up-to-date version of Tomcat 7. At the time of writing the latest is 7.0.67.

Comment: After updating tomcat to version 7.0.67, it throws java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets. It is [Java 7 API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html). The latest tomcat that won't throw this exception is 7.0.59.

Comment: Sorry, in that case you'll have to configure SSL yourself. Spring Boot relies on the changes made [for this issue](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56777) which are 7.0.66 and later.

Comment: Tomcat's [documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html) states that Tomcat 7 only requires Java 6. Are you sure that it's Tomcat itself that needs `StandardCharsets`?

Comment: spring-boot-starter-web depends on tomcat-embed-websocket which requires Java 7 according to Tomcat's [documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html). I think this is the reason why Spring Boot specify tomcat 7.0.59 in the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-use-tomcat-7).

Comment: OK, I am now able to use HTTPS using example in Spring Boot [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-enable-multiple-connectors-in-tomcat).